# Spring JDBC Mapper with complex data types

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am working on a web Application based on spring and salespoint framework. Within this project we created a `ConcreteOrde`r class which is saved via hibernate in a repo and with this in a sql database. 
The repo extends `PagingAndSortingRepository`. There are some findBy Methods but no one for an interval. The `ConcreteOrder` got a timestamp with `LocalDateTime`. I implemented a public default method which takes all Orders and put that ones whiche are within the interval in a new list:

```
public default Iterable<ConcreteOrder> findByInterval(Interval interval) {
    LocalDateTime end = interval.getEnd();
    LocalDateTime begin = interval.getStart();
    Collection<ConcreteOrder> collect = new ArrayList<ConcreteOrder>();
    Iterable<ConcreteOrder> allOrders = this.findAll();
    for (ConcreteOrder order : allOrders) {
        LocalDateTime orderTime = order.getDateOrdered();
        if ((orderTime.isBefore(end) || orderTime.isEqual(end)) && (orderTime.isAfter(begin) || orderTime.isEqual(begin))) {
            collect.add(order);
        }
    }
    Iterable<ConcreteOrder> iter = (Iterable<ConcreteOrder>)collect;
    return iter;
}
```

I guess this is pretty slow (correct my if I'm wrong). That's why I want implement a database search with Spring JDBC. The the Data Access Object interface is no problem, but the mapper is quite tricky. I use this example: [Spring JDBC Exmaple](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_example.htm)

The ResultSet can access types link int and String but I have to access own types respectivly spring types like `UserAccount`. Could you please show me how to access such objects.

Comment: If you already use Spring Data repositories, why don't you just create a repository method with a custom query in a `@Query` annotation? You can either use JPQL or native SQL.

Comment: Why would you need SQL for that... Just write a finder method for it... Spring Data supports whatever your JPA provider supports and you can simply write a query for in between datas. So I don't see why you would need to write a SQL query with a custom `RowMapper` for this.